# Transitions between fragments in BottomNavigationView

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

When navigating between fragments, the current fragment is displayed at the bottom (the icon is highlighted). But when you press the "back" button and walk on the stack, bottomnavigation somehow does not work and freezes on the last manually pressed element. How to fix?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Fragment selectedFragment = new AFragment();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new AFragment()).commit();
    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    selectedFragment = new AFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_search:
                    selectedFragment = new BFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_add:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), CreateMeetActivity.class));
                    setBorderActive(v_3);
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_notifications:
                    selectedFragment = new CFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_profile:
                    selectedFragment = new DFragment();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.fragment_container, selectedFragment).commit();
            return true;
        }
    };

}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you really have to create a new instance of the Fragment each time?

Comment: @remedy. And how to do it correctly?

Comment: @СергейГуков are the active/non-active images the same size with the same amount of padding?

Comment: @RayHunter I don't know what you mean

Comment: @СергейГуков check my answer below how to find out.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the **Developer Option** **Show layout bounds** to see what is happening with the Bottom Navigation Tab.

Under **Developer options** -> **Drawing** -> **Show layout bounds** and turn that on. Then you will be able to see what is happening with the layout.

Then you get something similar to the following:

[image: screenshot of the developer option - show layout bounds]